# When to use "a" vs "an"

Tags: grammar

When is the appropriate time to use "a" vs "an"?

For example, "*I have a array of...*" vs "*I have an array of...*"

I may be mistaken but I would typically use *an* in this case.

Firstly, am I correct to use *an* in this case? Secondly, is there a rule of thumb or grammatical rule that defines the appropriate usage? Lastly, If there is a grammatical rule, what is a recognized resource to its definition?

Comment: Closed now and will merge so it can't get downvoted further. I can't quite blame people for downvoting, though, as this question has been asked, and answered, [over 70 times](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/152?lq=1) by now. You will find it not once but thrice in the [top 15 most frequently asked questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles), and thrice in the top three questions in the [articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles) tag. We have a [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/), too.